# Calculating the percentage difference in values between two columns in SQL returning 0

Tags: sql, percentage

I'm working on table that will create output with quarter by quarter increases in figures. I basically have two columns with values for each quarter (`"Q1 2013"` and `"Q4 2012"`). I have created another column that gives the difference between the two values (`"Q/Q"`). I want to create another column that will then convert the difference as a percentage (`"Q%"`). My code currently looks like this:

```
SELECT STATION, "Q4 2012", "Q1 2013", "Q/Q", (("Q/Q"/"Q4 2012") * 100.00) AS "Q%"
FROM "STATION FIGURES";
```

The output I get in `Q%` is only `0.00` which is kind of annoying. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? Would appreciate any help.

Comment: Is the database SQL Server?

Comment: Are "Q/Q" and "Q4 2012" both type integer?  If so, then try `(("Q/Q" * 100.00)/"Q4 2012") AS "Q%"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL Server does integer division when the two values are integers.  Convert one to a decimal representation or float:

```
SELECT STATION, "Q4 2012", "Q1 2013", "Q/Q",
       ((cast("Q/Q" as float)/"Q4 2012") * 100.00) AS "Q%"
FROM "STATION FIGURES";
```

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me so quickly. mbeckish, your solution worked a charm!